# How can we manufacture different products in AnyLogic in batch with a setup time for each batch?

Tags: anylogic

**Problem:**
We have three different products that will be machined in a manufacturing line. Each product has differnet cycle time and once a product is machined some setup or change over is required to prepare the line for next product.

**What we could build:**
I have built a simple process flow but unable figure out how can I achieve the above.

1. [Process Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcOt1.png)
2. [Running Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwNjv.png)
3. [Production Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GSgV.png)

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is it that you can't achieve? Are you asking about how to add functionality for changeover? Also, how many resource units do you have in the pool and what do they represent?

Comment: Yes I am unable to add the functionality for change over.
Let's assume the bactch sizes are
ProductA - 25,
ProductB - 30,
ProductC - 35.

Considering 3 Resoruce Units in the Pool

Comment: Further questions: is resource pool unit per machine? if so, then why not 3 separate pools? can changeover on machine1 start while machine2 is still working on a previous batch or does the whole line have to be clear for changeover? How do you identify ProductA vs ProductB, are they represented by separate agents or is there an agent called Product with a property which changes from A to B depending on Source?

Comment: 3 different resource pool with 1 machine in each pool makes sense. I have added a project plan better explain the problem. Once a specific product type is complete change over will be required before next starts. For same product type change over is not required.

Comment: You will be able to address this in my design below. If you comment there on anything that is unclear I add to it as needed

Comment: @Jaco-BenVosloo thanks for the suggestion. The model you have suggested all the product is being processed parallely. And I am also unable to assign different cycle time for each product. I might be missing something here.

Comment: I am don't understand why you say thins are processed parallelly? Unless you increase the capacity of the size and the delay blocks beyond 1 there will always just be 1 product processed by any machine. 
See my updated answer for creating different products and setting different delays.

Comment: The additional update is useful. Thanks @Jaco-BenVosloo 
To clarify my earlier point on 'processed parallelly' I was trying to figure out a way to schedule the complete batches of ProductA - 25, ProductB - 30, ProductC - 35 in sequence. So that we can optimize the setup time required.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and clarification. I think your scheduling and batching problem can be resolved with 3 different queues for the different product types and a batch block for each... But this deserves a separate and new question ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your current setup and your clarification that it is more about adding in the setup delays I can suggest the following:

1. You need to have separate seize, delay, release instead of a service block

That way you can create a setup delay before the manufacturing starts or even after the manufacturing

[image]

Your setup and manufacturing delay can then be based on what the previous product was that you worked on and what the current product is etc.

I would suggest you a parameter inside your product agent that you can set to indicate which product you are crating

[image]

[image]

Then you can setup different delays based on the product type and you can do the same for the setup delay

[image]

If you are going to create more complex machines like in my example I would suggest putting them inside a new agent and putting all the general functionality in the agent.

[image]

I hope this answers your question or puts you on the right track